# Plotly: How to set marker symbol shapes for multiple traces using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have been trying to change the marker shape in plotly scatter plot but I can't seem to find the correct options. The plotly document goes over the size and opacity, but not the marker shape. Here's my sample code-

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Date': ['01/01/1990','01/01/1990','01/01/1990','01/01/1990',
             '01/01/2000','01/01/2000','01/01/2000','01/01/2000',
             '01/01/2010','01/01/2010','01/01/2010','01/01/2010',
             '01/01/2020','01/01/2020','01/01/2020','01/01/2020'
             ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Metric1']=[100, 110, 120, 130,
 200, 210, 220, 230,
 300, 310, 320, 330,
 400, 410, 420, 430]
df['Marker']=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
df['Color']=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
fig = px.scatter(df, x='Date', y='Metric1', color = 'Color', hover_data = ["Color", "Marker"])
fig.show()
```

Is it possible to implement what I am trying to do with Plotly scatter plot?I tried the follow the discussion in this forum- https://community.plotly.com/t/getting-different-markers-shapes/9944
But I am having a difficult time relating it to my problem
I am using Python 3.8 and Plotly 4.11.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### The answer:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='Date', y='Metric1',
                 color = 'Color', hover_data = ["Color", "Marker"],
                 symbol = df['Marker'],
                 symbol_sequence= ['circle-open', 'circle', 'circle-open-dot', 'square'],
                 color_discrete_sequence = ['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'brown'])
```

#### Some details:

Using plotly express, all you have to do is specify:

```
symbol = df['Marker']
# or simply symbol = 'Marker' if df is specified in px.scatter
```

...where `marker` is *not* the marker [type](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/#custom-marker-symbols) but rather a value that separates the data categories from eachother. Much like in your example with:

```
11    4
12    1
13    2
14    3
15    4
```

This will give you:

[image]

If you're not happy with the designated symbols, you can assign your own through:

```
symbols = ['square', 'circle-dot', 'circle', 'circle-open']
fig.px.scatter([...], symbol_sequence = symbols)
```

You probably already know that you can find a complete symbols list on [plotly.com/python/marker-style/](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/). And to replicate your original figure, only improved with a fully working legend, all you have to do to assign your colors of choice is:

```
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'brown']
px.scatter([...], color_discrete_sequence = colors)
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Date': ['01/01/1990','01/01/1990','01/01/1990','01/01/1990',
             '01/01/2000','01/01/2000','01/01/2000','01/01/2000',
             '01/01/2010','01/01/2010','01/01/2010','01/01/2010',
             '01/01/2020','01/01/2020','01/01/2020','01/01/2020'
             ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Metric1']=[100, 110, 120, 130,
                 200, 210, 220, 230,
                 300, 310, 320, 330,
                 400, 410, 420, 430]
df['Marker']=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
df['Color']=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
             'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
             'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
             'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

symbols = ['circle-open', 'circle', 'circle-open-dot', 'square']
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'brown']

fig = px.scatter(df, x='Date', y='Metric1', color = 'Color', hover_data = ["Color", "Marker"],
                 symbol = df['Marker'],
                 symbol_sequence=symbols,
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors
                )
fig.show()
```

Comment: IMHO, using `symbol_map={1:'circle-open', 2:'circle', 3:'circle-open-dot', 4:'square'}` is a more intuitive alternative here (along with `color_discrete_map`). The manner in which Plotly cycles through the `sequences` is sometimes non-intuitive. For example, replacing your code with `df['Marker']=[2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,4]` gives you something quite unexpected in that we expect `1` to map to `circle-open` and `2` to map to `circle`, but the opposite occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure it out-

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.validators.scatter.marker import SymbolValidator
import plotly.offline as pyo
vals = SymbolValidator().values
def Setcolor (x):
    if x == "a":
        return "blue"
    elif x == "b":
        return "orange"
    elif x == "c":
        return "green"
    else:
        return "brown"

def Setshape (x):
        vals = SymbolValidator().values
        return vals[3*x]
plot1 = go.Scatter(
                    x=df['Date'], y=df['Metric1'], 
                    marker = dict(color=list(map(Setcolor, df['Color'])), symbol = list(map(Setshape, df['Marker']))),
                    mode='markers',name='Show1', showlegend = True
                   )

fig = go.Figure(data=[plot1])

pyo.plot(fig,filename='final_plot.html')
```

Now my plot is not showing a legend. I am pretty sure it's an easy fix, but can't figure out what I am missing!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should accept your own answer, and ask about the legend in a separate question so people know that it's a question you have.

Comment: @Deepak Your suggestion is missing a few imports and will not run properly as it now stands. With the imports in place, your code *is* showing a legend. But only one instance since you've used *one* `go.Scatter` trace.